# What's the destructive power of the Rasengan about?

Tags: naruto, boruto

When you get hit by the Chidori, one of the damages you get is you get electrified since it's made of electricity.

What about the Rasengan? Since the Rasengan isnt made of electricity, what's the damage it's supposed to make? Does it burn? Is it sharp and by rotating you get cut? I discount that the damage comes from the impact, because since it isnt thrown many times and it isnt propelled, the damage and inertia of the Rasengan would be similar to a punch, and it wouldnt make sense to create a technique that does the same damage than a punch.

What's the destructive power of the Rasengan about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Rasengan being an incomplete jutsu, had no elemental chakra nature until amplified by Naruto Uzumaki.

As you've said, Chidori being of Raiton (Lightning Release) electrecutes the user upon hitting them. If hit with a Fire-Style jutsu, you'd burn. The damage received goes along with the elemental chakra nature the jutsu is of. But as I've already said, Rasengan is an incomplete jutsu and had no chakra nature, simply a spiral ball of chakra.

But because Rasengan is chakra compressed in a ball, spinning and/or rotating at incredibly high speeds, upon being hit with it, a wound that is sprial appears wherever the enemy was hit. This was shown when Naruto hit Kabuto with a Rasengan. On other cases, the enemy is sent flying.

Answer (score -1):

when naruto uses his wind style rasen-shuriken Tsunade described it as once it hits something it cannot slice it produces a vortex of wind in the immediate area creating countless microscopic wind blades, so many that even the Sharingan can't count them all. The wind blades pierce every cell in the body, disconnecting them from the Chakra circulatory system and so preventing them from providing their physical energy to the chakra-creation process. Because of this, the target loses their ability to create and mould chakra, damage which cannot be healed by medical ninjutsu.Tsunade likens the damage to poison, and warns that if the damage is great enough, those affected by it won't be able to use jutsu again.